# Form repaint issues after display resolution change

Tags: listview, delphi, vcl, repaint

I have a Delphi GUI application which runs just fine, until a display resolution change automatically causes the GUI window of the program to be repainted. We can catch this display event through the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message.

On the repaint event, it seems that some `TListView` components, which are hidden in that moment, are not repainted until they become visible again.

It seems that the repaint is called only on the visible components of the form, and the OS repaints the invisible items just when they become visible again.

However, this causes issues when the code references items in a `TListView` which, after the `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message, wasn't shown yet. The `TListView` should have items inside, but `TListView.Items.Count` returns 0, as if the `TListView` is empty.

After I make the `TListView` visible on screen, everything works again, and I can again reference the items in the `TListView`.

I tried to explicitly call `TListView.Repaint()` to update it without having to show it, but it does not work.

Is this documented behaviour?

Is there a way to repaint an invisible form component immediately, without having it to be visible on screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ListView.Items.Count` returns 0 if no handle is allocated. To make it return the correct value call `ListView.HandleNeeded` right before.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm when I call `ListView.HandleNeeded` right before `ListView.Items.Count`.
On the other hand, if I call `ListView.HandleNeeded` inside the WM_DISPLAYCHANGE callback, the problem persists. Any idea why? Maybe because the callback gets called before the actual repainting?

Comment: Most likely the handle es destroyed after the message is handled.